# What's the fastest way to performing horizontal sum on word32 for qualcomm hexagon 600 processors

Tags: c++, hexagon-dsp

I have been looking at the intrinsic for 600 series and there isn't a horizontal sum intrinsic for hvx similar to that on x86. I have been looking for something that lets me reverse the register content so that i can continuously add the reverse of a register to itself till i end up with the correct sum which i can extract.

Comment: Neon has vector multiply accumulate.  You might be able to multiply with a one vector then accumulate the result to get what you want.  That chip also has a GPU, you might be able to write an old-fashioned GPGPU kernel in openGL to do it too.  GPU and CPU probably share memory so no marshalling if you do it right.

Comment: @SeanMcAllister But that means that i first have to move the data from hvx register to some array then load that in neon intrinsic. wouldn't that consume a lot of time.

Comment: @SeanMcAllister  Sorry I forgot to mention in the question am using hvx

Comment: Ah I see this is just a single hvx register? or summing a larger array?  Looking at the programmer's reference, there _is_ a multiply-accumulate instruction (vrmpy) that you could multiply with a 1 vector and reduce down to a single value in HVX.

Comment: @SeanMcAllister its a single hvx 32bit integers which was the result of multiply-reduce 4way on 8bit unsigned hvx vector

Comment: @SeanMcAllister looking over vrmpy, i see i doesn't accept input of 32 bit

Answer (score 0):

To reduce a vector on HVX, use log2 steps of valign / vror and your operator (max/min/add/etc)

You could use vdelta/vrdelta to reverse the register, but I think you want a rotate instead.

Here is an example of reducing two vectors of words (one partial min and one partial max) to get the total min and max:

https://source.codeaurora.org/quic/hexagon_nn/nnlib/tree/hexagon/asm_src/vrmaxmin_h.S